# This location is unknown

Tags: amadeus

Today I started getting `This location is unknown` errors on almost every Flight Offers Search call to the test API. I'm using this data https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md to make requests.

The kind of error that I get is this:

```
{
    "code": 4926,
    "title": "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
    "detail": "This location code is unknown",
    "status": 400
}
```

Is there something going on today with test API? On friday everything worked.

Comment: We had an issue with Flight Offers Search in the test environment that has been fixed, you shouldn't face any problem from now on

Comment: @AnthonyRoux Yeah, thanks. I noticed that on the next day :)